# Creating a program that lets the user input a maximum and minimum value then lets the user choose from those numbers to add to a total tally

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program in python that lets the user pick a maximum value and a minimum value, then continuously adds this to the total. This has to use a 'while' loop. If the user enters a negative value, then the program ends and shows the sum of the valid numbers. This is what I have so far:

'''

```
min_ = int(input('Enter the minimum value: '))
max_ = int(input('Enter the maximum value: '))

number = int(input(f'Enter a number between {min_} and {max_} to add to the total: '))
total = 0
while number > 0:
total += number
      int(input(f'Enter a number between {min_} and {max_} to add to the total: '))
if number < min_ and number > max_ :
      print('Invalid number')
      int(input(f'Enter a number between {min_} and {max_} to add to the total: '))
else:
      print('Sum of all valid numbers you entered: ', total)
```

'''

Comment: Your indentation is off. That will affect Python code.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: A number is invalid if it's less than min *or* greater than max. It can't be both so you should not use *and*.

Comment: The values inputted inside the loop are not being assigned to any variable, so once `number` was inputted, its value is going to be constant and you'll have an infinite loop is `number` was >0.

Comment: My indentation is not off. It just seems off because of how I had to put it in the question. My question is when I run this program, I cannot get it to stop the loop as I want it to stop when there is a negatvie number and print out the 'Sum of all valid numbers: ' but when I ran it, the loop never ended.

Comment: There's no good reason for the code to not look correctly indented in your post. You should fix it so that it matches your actual code. Otherwise we are debugging in the dark.

Comment: Sorry, first time using this site for help.

Answer (score 0):

In line 8 you forgot to assign the input to your variable number. So number is always the input you first gave.

edit: You probably also want to add to your total after you received the input or your output will always be one iteration off.
Please consider a different condition for your loop and then use the `break` keyword in your else block to exit the loop.

Comment: How do you assign a input to my variable number? Sorry really beginner coder and sometimes I do not know what I am doing.

Comment: In line four you have something like: `number = int(input(f'Enter a number between {min_} and {max_} to add to the total: '))` where you create a variable called number and give it the value of your input. In your code you are asking the user for input two more times (line 8 and 11) but you are not "saving" the input to a variable.